# How to integrate Login with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app, php, developer-edition

I have registered a Developers Edition.

When try to connect to their API it returned me an error saying "API_DISABLE_ORG" something like that.

They said that i have to contact Salesforce for this. I already did, its been 2 days already, no response.

I'm using Laravel 4.2 with PHP5.6

I don't want to register a plan in Salesforce. I want customers to login in my app with their salesforce with plan and retrieve their `contacts` `notes` `documents` and others.

Comment: Salesforce no longer responds to requests for support cases for DE orgs. They will simply point you to the developer forums. If they actually help you consider yourself lucky....Also, make sure your profile in the org you are calling has API Enabled checked int he user profile

Answer (score 0):

There can be following reasons:-

API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG means API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner. You cannot integrate Salesforce with external system. You need to contact Salesforrce to enable API. You must have purchased license to leverage Salesforce support.

OR

If you are using Professional Edition than you can add API access giving an additional fee. There is no technical solution except these.

OR

Check your profile here that check box is checked or not.

[image]

Comment: how do i contact them? i couldn't find any contact email support. can you redirect me to it? please

Comment: i couldn't also find the administrative permissions